# How to delete orphaned records from sysmergesubscriptions table?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have some old orphaned records for old subscriptions that I want to delete from the sysmergesubscriptions table.

Each time I delete unnecessary records, it show up again after it syncs with any subscriber!!

How can I delete these records permanently ?

P.S : These records were left out in this table even after I cleaned up our Merge Replication Setup in my question : [How to properly clean Merge Replication Setup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44655/14753)